# my jquery code run without click , i mean after refreshing the page , what shoud i change in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, refresh

my jquery code run without click , i mean after refreshing the page , what shoud i change in it

```
<script>
( function( $ ) {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])', function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
      var hashStr = this.hash.slice(1);
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hashStr +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top -150 } , 1000);
        window.location.hash = hashStr;
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? You say `my jquery code run without click` but it clearly runs WITH a click

Comment: i thought like you but it runs without click after the page load , i dont know why

Comment: There must be something else running, because this code should not run without a click